# Error while trying to open image in new tab in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

URL in browser :

```
mysite.com/media/images/Tulips_P0asGX5.jpg
```

Error I get is:

```
Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL: mysite.com/media/images/Tulips_P/403.shtml

Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'my/path/to/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The image exists in media/images directory, the path given is correct.

Comment: Your template?? Also, separate your problem with tracebacks properly.. it looks messy

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: show us the settings.py file